# DB constraint violation not throwing Exception in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following code:

```
try {
    userDAO1.save(userRecord);
    userDAO2.save(userRecord);
}
catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    throw new ApplicationException("Contraint violated")
}
```

userDAO1.save(userRecord) violates an integrity constraint - so after the entire code has been run, there is nothing written to the table userDAO1 refers to.

However, the userDAO1.save() statement doesn't throw an error/exception - so userDAO2.save() is executed as well.

But the DataIntegrityViolationException is caught, and the **stack trace is null**.

How do I check where the DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown from, and prevent userDAO2.save() from being executed if userDAO1.save() violates a constraint?

I tried adding a @Transactional annotation around this code, but that didn't work either.

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (UNIQUE_EMAIL) violated
; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UNIQUE_EMAIL]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (UNIQUE_EMAIL) violated

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:516)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.updateUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.osiris.UserReg.UpdateUserCommand.execute(UpdateUserCommand.java:63)
```

The code I've posted is in UpdateUserCommand, which is annotated with `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: Read the javadoc of save() or persist() or merge() or whatever is called in the DAO.save() method. It doesn't tell that an insert query is executed whe calling this method. And I very much doubt the stack trace is null. Add `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block, and you'll see it. And wrap the DataIntegrityViolationException in your ApplicationException.

Comment: Not related to answer but Are you catching `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception in Service layer?, looking at your code it seems you are doing so. Not a good Idea. Service layer has nothing to do with Dao layer exceptions.

Comment: I've simplified the code for posting purposes - there is a separate business layer.

@Nizet - I added a printStackStrace(), the only classes that are mentioned are internal spring classes - nothing that I wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit of a tricky one, but I'll do my best.
Hibernate will only commit a transaction when the method annotated with @Transactional exits. Hence your DataIntegrityViolationException will only be catchable after that method returns. There is no way that you can get Hibernate to not call `UserDAO2.save()` because it can't detect that a violation has occurred. I'll provide an example below

```
@Service
/*These variable names are used for clarity's sake, I don't actually use these names myself*/
public UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    @Autowired
    private HibernateUserDAO1 userDao1;
    @Autowired
    private HibernateUserDAO2 userDao2

    @Transactional
    /*Put your try catch block around where this method is called*/
    public void saveUserDao1(User user){
         userDao1.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    /*Only call this if saveUserDao1 succeeds*/
    public void saveUserDao2(User user){
          userDao2.saveOrUpdate(user)
    }
}
```

Then in your HibernateUserDAO1:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(User user){
     currentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

The exception can only be caught above your service layer. Ideally what you want to be doing, is individual saves using 2 different DAO's and checking that the first succeeded before doing the second.

EDITED:
Also be aware that Hibernate will not pick up private methods annotated with @Transactional because Hibernate depends on creating Proxy objects from the interface that your class implements. No interface definition = no proxy object = no Hibernate Session. So you can't call a private method annotated with @Transactional. I'd try to make your SessionFactory an object in an abstract superclass and have both DAO's inherit from this. A better option is to use 2 transaction managers each pointing to your different databases, then specify which database things are saving too. That way you can use just 1 DAO, and use whichever session factory you require to do your saves.

Comment: The code that I posted is in a method annotated with '@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)'.

Shouldn't the userDAO2.save() statement be rolled back as well?

Comment: Are you actually using 2 different DAO's, if you are then userDAO2.save() will not be rolled back, as it will (usually) have a different SessionFactory instance hence a different Session. Hibernate will only rollback the transaction in the session that caused an exception.

Comment: Can you post whatever the stacktrace says, along with the relevant excerpt from your service layer, your hibernate config and the object that this is all working on?

Comment: and now that I think about it, why are you using 2 different DAO's to save the same object?

Comment: I've added the stack trace. The 2 DAO's point to two different tables (one is in a different DB)

Comment: Your issue is being caused by having the 2 separate DAO's. Also you are using Hibernate 3 so putting @Transactional would have no effect if you aren't using an AnnotationSessionFactoryBean in your session factory. You can solve this issue by attempting to save your object in 1 DAO then checking for a DataIntegrityViolationException, then saving using the other DAO. This sounds like a mess, you might need to look at refactoring your DAO's and objects to make things simpler. Can I also suggest updating to Hibernate 4. It has much better support for annotation driven transaction management.

Comment: Thanks. I moved the first DAO call to a new transaction, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What made you to believe that DataIntegrityViolationException was not thrown while the statement **userDAO1.save()** was executed? Also, why do you believe that the statement **userDAO2.save()** was executed as well?

If the above opinions were made upon observations of code execution progression in an IDE debug console such as that of Eclipse then the interpretations might be wrong.

Please try to observe the results by punching-in some debug statements like the ones below, and executing the code. This may help you to find out the root cause of the failure -

```
try {
    userDAO1.save(userRecord);
    System.out.println("-- After userDAO1.save(userRecord) --");
    userDAO2.save(userRecord);
    System.out.println("-- After userDAO2.save(userRecord) --");
} catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new ApplicationException("Contraint violated")
}
```

Comment: A new record was added in the table that userDAO2 points to. 

I also tried putting a try {} catch(Exception e){} around userDAO1.save(), but no exception was caught.

Comment: Hmm... this could be because of the fact that Hibernate by default executes the required SQL statements only when the corresponding **Transaction/Session object is committed/closed**. Hence the exceptions were not thrown when the **save()** was called. Please try to catch the exception where you are committing or closing the Transaction or Session object.